# What to share of a C# project on Google Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, google-code

I have a C# project in MS Visual Studio 2008 that I would like to share on Google Code...I am not sure exactly which files I should be sharing on Google Code if I want to involve other contributors? What I am exactly unsure about is whether to share the entire solution folder or just the .cs files? And if it's the latter how does a contributor go about building the solution and the directory structure?
Thanks

Comment: Looking at the other C# projects that have been posted might give you a better idea on what, specifically, you should include. It's going to be somewhere between the entire solution folder and just the .cs files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I would include the project file(s) and solution file(s) as part of the source code in a team environment (such as at work), especially if they contain anything that's needed for the proper building of the code (build events, DLL references, etc.).  The user file(s) and suo file(s) and stuff like that aren't needed, those are user-specific.  But this is in an environment where it can be safely assumed that everybody is using Visual Studio, even the same version.

The code itself doesn't *need* the project/solution files to be built, and the less you can depend on them the more open-source-friendly the project really is.  If the code can be properly built from the command line, or with a tool such as NAnt, then an open source project may be better off with that.  So, just from a separation of concerns perspective, try to keep the dependency on the project file(s) as light or non-existent as possible.

Overall, including the project file(s) and solution file(s) is fine if your intended audience is expected to be using Visual Studio.